# C++ Repeated type in instance variable initializer

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following class with instance variable a initialized to a vector of length 3:

```
class A {
 public:
  vector<int> a = vector<int>(3); 
};
```

This works fine, but notice that the type vector is repeated twice. Is there any way to write that type just once? (In real life, I'm dealing with way more verbose type names.)

I thought this ought to work:

```
class A {
 public:
  vector<int> a(3); 
};
```

but nope, it doesn't for C++11 anyway, perhaps because that looks suspiciously like 'a' is declared as a member function.

Comment: I mean, you really shouldn't be instantiating your variables outside of a constructor. So, that fixes one issue.

Comment: @DavidBittner what's wrong with default initializers?

Comment: I thought this was against good practices. If not, then TIL

Comment: @DavidBittner in this case you were right. The default initializer didn't do what I wanted it to do. It made a vector with one element: 3.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, but I was wrong. I had thought it was bad practice to use a default initializer within a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do anything like this. Either you have to use your first solution, or do the following:

```
class A {
private:
    vector<int> a; 
public:
    A() : a(3) {};
};
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8016451262eb1e8e)

Comment: I think you want to remove the `vector<int> a(3);`, because as OP said, that is not valid C++. Also, `vector<int> a{3};` does something completely different because that is list initialization which prefers constructors with `std::initializer_list`s.

Comment: @Rakete1111 fixed, was a syntax error! Oh yeah, that skipped my mind, the other syntax does a different thing. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use braced initialization syntax:

```
class A 
{
   vector<int> a{1,2,3}; 
};
```

Now vector contains three elements.